# Laravel: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to update Laravel using the **composer update**. I'm following the guide at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade but am getting stuck when running composer update.

*Note: I don't have "bootstrap/cache/compiled.php".

I've updated the composer.json as follows:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "illuminate/html": "5.0.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

The console throws the following errors:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you already tried to remove / alter the laravelcollective/html dependency to a newer version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `laravelcollective` package points to a version that requires <= 5.2.* of the `Laravel Core`

Manually update it, then re-run it:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0"
```